# python 2.7 Tkinter reading environment variables

Tags: python, bash, tkinter

I am new to using Tkinter in pythyon 2.7 and am not able to read environment variables I defined on a raspberry pi.
I have read how most problems was because the environment variables were not exported, but not sure that is my problem. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The python app is run from a bash script

This works, I can run the bash script and echo the contents of the environment variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
export USR_USR
echo $USR_USR
python netid_button2.py
```

This works, when I work with a very simple python script and work with Tkinter, I can read the environment variable PATH.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
import os

top = Tkinter.Tk()

vusr_usr = get('PATH')
user_envd = open('user_envd.txt','w+')
user_envd.write('v_usr= ' + str(vusr_usr) + '\n')
user_envd.close()

top.mainloop()
```

This does not work. I cannot read the environment variable I created for my app.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
import os

top = Tkinter.Tk()

vusr_usr = get('USR_USR')
user_envd = open('user_envd.txt','w+')
user_envd.write('v_usr= ' + str(vusr_usr) + '\n')
user_envd.close()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Neither of your examples will work, because `get` isn't a known command. Please post code that actually runs.

Comment: Sorry it was vusr_usr = os.environ.get('USR_USR') that I used there.  When searching someone said they used just get(), but you are right no that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have an enviromental variable FOO that was set in bash like:

```
export USR_USR=somevalue
```

This is how you access the same environmental variable in python:

```
import os

print os.environ["USR_USR"]

"somevalue"
```

The rest of your python program will be able to access that enviromental variable

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to read the environment variable from the Python Tkinter app, not to create one.  I don't know why I can read the PATH env, but not read the USR_USR environment variable I created.

Comment: os.environ contains all the enviormental variables. I updated my code to access the one you created in the bash script

Comment: Oh yes, that works for me too.  However, I also import Tkinter so I can make a gui and I think that is when I can no longer read the environment variable.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I launch it from a bash script like below.

Comment: sorry hit return too fast. it is launched from a bash script

    #!/bin/bash
    export USR_USR

    echo $USR_USR

    python netid_button2.py

Comment: the line "export USR_USR"  does nothing, you need to set a value for USR_USR

Comment: I had set the value of USR_USR in the /etc/environment folder on the raspberry pi where I have other set.  I can echo and read the value in the bash script that calls the python app.

Comment: @markp: if it's already an environment variable, you don't need to recreate it. It's already in your environment. If you can read it in a bash script, you should be able to read it in a python script spawned from that bash script.

Comment: That is what I had thought too. But when I look at the txt file I write to for debugging it has a value of None for my environment var USR_USR.but when I substitute PATH as the variable it can read that.

Comment: The reason USR_USR has no value is because of line #2 in your bash script. If you export a enviormental variable without setting it equal to anything, it is the same as setting it equal to None

Comment: Thank you for that.  I bypassed the bash shell and ran the python script directly, but it still shows None for a USR_USR value.  But when I substitute PATH for USR_USR it shows data  v_usr= /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin.